# Better way to run this loop?

Tags: pandas

I have data in the following form:

```
    id    rr
    2.0   4
    2.0   5 
    2.0   4
    2.0   3
    5.0   4
    5.0   2 
    5.0   4
    5.0   1
    7.0   1
    7.0   2 
    7.0   3
    7.0   2
```

I would like to compute a specific parameter for each id. I wrote this and it works but this doesn't seem efficient , especially as the original data has 8760 rows for each id (436).

```
import pandas as pd 
sum_rr = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'id' ,'sum_rr2', 'sum_rr3'})

for i in id_cat.unique():
    test = data[data.id == i]
    test['sum_rr2'] = test.rr.rolling(3 , center = False).sum() - test.rr 
    test['sum_rr3'] = test.rr.rolling(4 , center = False).sum() - test.rr 
    sum_rr = sum_rr.append(test[['sum_rr3','sum_rr4','id']] , ignore_index = True)

sum_rr = sum_rr.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case try with `groupby` and `rolling`

```
data['sum_rr2'] = data.groupby('id')['rr'].rolling(3).sum().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)-data.rr
```